# How to run a process before anything else in a Node.js app?

Tags: node.js

I want to `decrypt` several `config` items based on environment variables before anything else starts running in a `Node.js` app.

I'm starting my app using the standard `node ./app.js`. Then I call a simple method from the top of my `app.js` file:

```
function setConfig() {
    var pass = process.env.pass;
    var conf = Encrypt.decrypt(encryptedConfig, pass);
    var configObj = JSON.parse(conf);
    // do stuff with the configObj
}
```

This works fine, but since everything is `async` other processes, which need the config variables, are already running and throwing errors.

What I want is to run my `setConfig()` before anything else. Is this doable?

Comment: *This works fine, but since everything is async* - what does this mean? The code in the question doesn't reflect that. Where does `Encrypt` come from?

Comment: @estus `Encrypt` is a module with encryption methods. I don't believe it's relevant to the question, which is how do you run a method before anything else runs in the app.

Comment: If it's not relevant, why did you state that 'everything is async'? The code you posted is synchronous. Just run `setConfig()` at the top of main module.

Comment: Like I said, running `setConfig` at the top of the main module does not execute before other code runs and fails. For example my database config doesn't have the host, and password info because they are not in the config yet. Maybe my comment about `everything async` is misleading. The question is simple: can I run anything in node.js express app and have it guaranteed to be the first code that executes on app startup?

Comment: *For example my database config doesn't have the host, and password info because they are not in the config yet* - can you provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for this problem? As I said, calling `setConfig` at the top of main module (app.js) will guarantee that it runs first, considering that `setConfig` is synchronous.

Comment: OK, yes, I can confirm it now. My issue is different. Thanks. If you want to turn this into an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Sure. Added some explanation for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a routine is synchronous, it can be executed before routines that depend on it. Executing it before anything else at the top of main module guarantees that there will be no race conditions:

```
setConfig();
require('module-that-depends-on-config');
```

If a routine is asynchronous, it should be treated as such in order to avoid race conditions. It's preferable for all asynchronous routines to return promises, so they could be chained with `async` function in main module:

```
(async () => {
  await setConfigAsync();
  require('module-that-depends-on-config');
  ...
})().catch(console.error);
```

Answer (score 2):

Apart from accepted answer, what might be useful in some situations (where you can't/don't want to modify the executed file) is `NODE_OPTIONS` environmental variable + `--require` (`-r`) param of `node executable`

```
NODE_OPTIONS='--require "./first.js"' node second.js
```

That way, `first.js` executes before `second.js`.

Docs:

- https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_node_options_options
- https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_r_require_module

Comment: For anyone using ES Modules `--experimental-loader=./first.js` does the same.